# How to change DataGrid Grouping Display to some other aggregate

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `PagedCollectionview` property of my View-Model.  I've added a `PropertyGroupDescription` to the `PagedCollectionView.GroupDescriptions`.

Currently the grouping heading displays the value of the property that is being grouped on, and an item count for that group.  What I would like is to add min,max, and sums of various values of the group, and display those in the header as well.  Is such a thing possible with the DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You should create own [DataGridRowGroupHeader Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowgroupheaderstyles%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/DataGridGroupRowHeaderUI.aspx).
Also look at [this sample](http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/summary-row-in-datagrid/)